# Reporting services 3 tables

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I recently had to start working with Microsoft SSRS3. I cannot ask the guy before me how he did it. I have two tables one under the other. If I run the report,  the other table is not directly under it but it moves far down. I dont know how to explain it properly as i am new to this. I just want to edit the already made reports and the only problem i have at the moment is, that I don't know how to "nest" another table right where the first table ends.
I attached the picture, above is the design mode and under is how it makes the gap if I run the report. Sorry for red blobs but there could be sensitive information there.

[image: Problem with tables]

Comment: In your report design you appear to have a text box and 2 list tablix but your report looks like it has 5 tablix?

Comment: It would help in providing a solution if you could publish your database table defintions, dataset queries and the xml code for your report. You can get the XML by right clicking on the report in Solution explorer and selecting view code - no data is shown so there should be no confidentiality issues - unless you want to disguise data base selects.

Comment: Actually that's a lot of work. Tablix in report server are prone to shift vertically or horizontally when a new tablix is added or some other tablix in the report is either amended or acquires more data from the data set query. In your example I would suspect the tablix to the left of the words GAP in your illustration.

Comment: I am sorry for a late reply, im guessing i took on more than i can handle and this wont be easy, right now im expecting a book on this subject and i guess there is no quick fix, il just have to go step by step from beggining. If i had some prior experience to this it would be ok but im completly new to this. I was just hoping there would be an easy way to set this together.

Comment: If you have not already done so have a look at Microsoft Virtual Academy and microsoft's SSRS tutorials. SSRS comes wrapped in the free  SQLExpress edition of SQL Server , Developer edition (also free) is essentially Enterprise edition with licensing restrictions and includes SSRS,SSDT,SSAS an SSIS - both should work fine on Windows pro and above if you fancy doing some home study.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem many months later. 
The reason for the gap was top lining. The tables that have another table right under them need to be differently aligned than any other table. If the position of first table is 20 points down and the second table has another table right underneath, the top table needs to be 20.5 or more or 19.5 or less and the tables will not make that gap.

[image: Tiny gap]